# 360 degrees product view with blender (using render)

Tags: rendering

how to get 360 degrees product view (render from 360 different angles lmao it's 360 jpeg/png file) in the blender, it's so long anyone has a shortcut
I'm gonna use these on my vb6 (a old programming language) project ( don't use GPU renders,I'm using CPU because I didn't have compatible one)

Answer (score 4):

To quickly make your camera turn around anything, you can use the Turnaround Camera addon. It is shipped by default with Blender.

More about it here: [Turnaround Camera — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/animation/turnaround_camera.html)

---

### Creating the turnaround setup

1. Go to the *Edit* menu > *Preferences* > *Addons* tab, search for "turnaround" and enable the addon;

   [image: addon prefs]
2. Hit <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Empty* > *Plain Axes*, place the empty object where you want your camera to rotate around. Do not rotate it yet. Make sure it's the only selected object;
3. In the *Sibebar* > *Animate* tab > *Turnaround Camera* panel, set the end frame to 360. X Y Z should be set to 0 0 1 by default. Then hit the *Turnaround Camera* button;

   [image: addon settings]
4. The addon should have created a new "MCH_(...)" as child of your empty, wearing the rotation animation, and parent of your scene's camera:

   [image: addon setup]
   If your camera doesn't look exactly where you want to, use the empty you created to move it up and down or sideways.
5. Select that MCH empty. In the timeline, you should see two keyframes. Select them all by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, and then set them to linear interpolation by pressing <kbd>T</kbd> > *Linear*.
6. Set your start frame at 1, and your end frame at 359. Now you should have a camera rotating around your stuff at exactly 1° per frame, for a total of 360 frames. Aka a full turnaround:

   [image: turnaround]

This example was made at double speed, otherwise 360 frames at 24fps is 15 seconds long...

For curiosity, why do you need 360 renders of the same product from all 360 degrees? No product preview uses all 360 angles, they use only a few, like 12 at every 30 degrees or so. 360 is enough to make a turn around for 15 seconds, that's quite slow and heavy on the server.

Answer (score 1):

For separate PNG files, used for example in product 360° degrees viewer, or configurator, you can do this:

Using keyframes, manually set angles in each frame, using keyframe auto-tracker. I set up my render like this - rotating object along Z-Axis while holding Ctrl (thats 5° each "click"), using right arrow key to go to the next frame, then do the same.

Then, in the render settings, make it as a PNG output. While rendering whole animation, this will create multiple PNGs with every angle you manually set up before. Set the frame length as well. If everything is set for you, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>F12</kbd> and it should start rendering separate PNG files in chosen directory.

The manual rotating took me like 8 minutes.

Comment: *"Using keyframes, manually set angles in each frame"* - manually set 360 keyframes? :D

Answer (score 0):

You want to output a Cycles render image.
create a camera, and place it in front of your "to render to 360" object.
Go to the camera's properties.
Enable "panoramic view". This will render a 360 latitudinal image. give the appropriate dimensions for the final render in the Output properties> format settings.

Now you need to use an [exif online code injector](https://www.thexifer.net/#exif-general). Choose any of the 360 exif camera metadata to inject it to your image render. If I recall well, I used to pick "theta.." something from the options. There are a lot of youtube videos showing how to do this step.

And just like that you can upload to any facebook page, or 360 online picture community that will display your 360 render from Blender. I created [an entire short animation](https://youtu.be/l7yLxtKo3-I) using the described method.

[image]

Comment: I don't think for a beginner it's enough to say 'enable panoramic view' to get a '360 latitudinal image'. By default, the panoramic camera is set to _Fisheye Equisolid_ with a 180° field of view. And even setting it to a FOV of 360° doesn't give the result you're talking of. I guess you mean the _Equirectangular_ panorama type. By the way, it's 180° latitudinal and 360° longitudinal.

Comment: Im not talking about panaroma getting jpegs that is in another angles

Comment: like 0.jpeg (0 degrees rotated) 1.jpeg 2.jpeg (it goes to 360.jpeg)

Comment: In other words you want to rotate the camera around your object and save an image at every 1°? https://youtu.be/Y9odlxWL_pI shows you how to do the rotation, but you'll probably also want to rotate any lights in the same way. Set the number of frames to 360 and save your output to an image format and Render > Animation.

Comment: yes its i need.

Comment: sorry i use 2.90

Comment: This is not a tutorial site, but my comment and that video should give you all you need. That should work fine in 2.90.

Comment: Isn't a panoramic view, about rendering a big angle around the camera, rather than orbiting the camera around an object? You could render the object from all angles with a panoramic camera, if you were interested about the **inside** of the object, and the camera would be inside it... In all fairness, though, the OP wasn't clear on what he meant, only L0Loc made it clearer with his answer...

Answer (score 0):

An old-school method, without add-ons, would be:

1. Set your animation length to 360 frames
2. Create a Curve > Circle (Here, called 'Camera_Path')
3. Give your rendering camera 2 constraints:

[image]

- *Follow Path*: to follow the circle (the axis settings are just for thoroughness). Click 'Animate Path'.
- *Track To*: aimed at your product, or, say, an Empty at your focal point.

4. In the circle's *Data* tab, check the 'Path Animation' panel, and
   set to 360 frames.

[image]

Set to render as .png, and you're done. You can adjust the height/size of the circle.. you can offset the start-point in the *Follow Path* constraint, etc...

[image]